# Attribute lookup precedence with descriptors and property objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, properties

I was taking a look into descriptors and how they are the mechanism used behind properties and functions. I'm a bit confused on how attributes are looked up when we're implementing a descriptor vs using properties.

```
class NonDataDescriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return 'non-data descriptor'

class DataDescriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        return 'data descriptor'
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        pass

class MyClass(object):
    descriptor_one = NonDataDescriptor()
    descriptor_two = DataDescriptor()

    def __init__(self):
        self.descriptor_one = 'hello'
        self.descriptor_two = 'goodbye'


mc = MyClass()
print(mc.descriptor_one)
print(mc.descriptor_two)
```

The output is:

```
hello
data descriptor
```

This makes sense because attribute lookup order is:

1. data descriptors
2. instance attributes in `instance_obj.__dict__`
3. non-data descriptors

Since properties really just implement descriptors, I'm wondering why this order of attribute lookup doesn't seem to be respected. See the following:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, fname, lname):
        self._fname = fname
        self._lname = lname

    @property
    def fullname(self):
        return '{} {}'.format(self._fname, self._lname)


mc = MyClass('Bob', 'John')
print(mc.fullname)
mc.__dict__['fullname'] = 'testing'
print(mc.__dict__)
print(mc.fullname)
```

The output is:

```
Bob John
{'_fname': 'Bob', '_lname': 'John', 'fullname': 'testing'}
Bob John
```

I was expecting since the property object, `fullname`, is really just a non data descriptor, that the instance attribute `fullname`, would take precedence.

Also, functions are implemented as non-data descriptors as well, and this order of attribute lookup is respected:

```
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
         self.display = 'display instance attribute'

    def display(self):
        print('display from instance method')

t = Test()
print(t.display)
```

The output is:

```
display instance attribute
```

Can anyone explain why it's different with property objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick lies in the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol) here:

> - If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with the same name as a data descriptor, the data descriptor takes precedence.
> - If an instance’s dictionary has an entry with the same name as a non-data descriptor, the dictionary entry takes precedence.

```
@property
def fullname(self):
    return '{} {}'.format(self._fname, self._lname)
```

This is a data descriptor, because the `property` object returned by the decorator always defines `__set__`, even if you don't define the setter (then `__set__` will raise an `AttributeError`, see [code here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ac20e0f98d6727ba97a9575bfa2a11b2f6247c35/Objects/descrobject.c#L1382)).

```
>>> MyClass.fullname
<property object at 0x7f30e3917958>
>>> MyClass.fullname.__set__
<method-wrapper '__set__' of property object at 0x7f30e3917958>
```

Thus, the data descriptor takes precedence.

Since the other examples already behave like you expect, this should be enough to complete your understanding.

Answer (score 0):

@spectras already answered your question. I just want to give additional method to check on descriptor:

```
In [517]: import inspect

In [518]: inspect.isdatadescriptor(type(mc).__dict__['fullname'])
Out[518]: True

In [519]: inspect.isdatadescriptor(MyClass.__dict__['fullname'])
Out[519]: True
```

So, @property always is data descriptor even you don't define `setter`. In that case, attribute assignment will raise `AttributeError: can't set attribute`